# jQuery Validation errorPlacement

Tags: jquery, validation

This works:

```
$("[id$='_zzz']").rules(
    "add",
    {
        required: true,
        minlength: 8,
        messages: {
            required: "...",
            minlength: jQuery.format("...")
        }            
    }
);
```

The error message comes up.

When I try to style the message, this doesn't work:

```
$("[id$='_zzz']").rules(
    "add",
    {
        required: true,
        minlength: 8,
        messages: {
            required: "...",
            minlength: jQuery.format("...")
        },
        errorElement: "span",
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            error.insertAfter(element);
            error.css("margin", "0 0 0 5px");
        }             
    }
);
```

When I style via the validate function, the styling is applied so it works:

```
$('#aspnetForm').validate({
    errorElement: "span",
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.insertAfter(element);
        error.css("margin", "0 0 0 5px");
    }
});
```

Why can't I style using errorplacement in the rules add function?

Comment: Which jquery libraries are you using?

Comment: bassistance.de - http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods

Comment: OK, I can confirm that the styling works on a simple page (using jquery1.4/validate) - there doesn't appear to be anything wrong with styling it at the same time ... give me a minute.

Comment: Sorry unexpected influx of work, I'll look at it tonight - but someone will probably have solved it by then!

Comment: No problem.  I can style the messages using validate, this is more of a why question in terms of why can't I do it with the rules function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first method, you're passing a `errorPlacement` property/function on the object to the rules method...it simply doesn't care of check for this and doesn't use it.  For any object you pass in to javascript it has to check for that property or make use of it in some manner, otherwise it's just extraneous information.  You could add `myExtrathing:'ValueHere'` to the object as well, wouldn't break anything...but wouldn't be used either.

The [`.validate()` method has an existing `errorPlacement` function](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options) (that is actively uses, that's the important part, it's *looking* for it) in the default options and [performs an extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) to replace the default method with the one your provided...if you provided one.  This same behavior is true for almost every jQuery plugin and any option you specify, it merges the default options with the ones you provide/override.  You can see some simple examples of this behavior [in the jQuery plugin authoring manual](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Options).